# Выполнение арифметических действий в строке Lua

Tags: lua

У меня есть строка:

```
local test = "5+5";
```

Мне нужно, чтобы в ней произвелись арифметические действия(всегда на входе строка).
Пробовал вызвать функцию `tonumber`, но она выводит nil.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый ^_^

Answer (score 1):

`tonumber` используется только для преобразование числа из строкового формата.

Для вычислений есть [`load`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-load):

```
test = "5 + 5"
func = assert(load("return " .. test))
test2 = func()
print(test2)
```

В 5.1 используйте [`loadstring`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-loadstring).